# Creating the converter bean

Tags: java

I'm new to learning `Spring`. I use the built-in `Spring` converter in my application. But in the service layer, when creating the constructor, it does not see the converter bean.

How to transfer the converter bean to `Spring`?

My error code:

> Parameter 1 of constructor in ru.web.service.ClientService required a
> bean of type 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter' in your
> configuration.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your class `Converter` as a bean and change your `ClientService` annotation to `@Service`.

Converter.java

```
@Component
public class Converter<M, D>
```

ClientService.java

```
@Service
public class ClientService
```

Comment: I plan to use this converter in other classes and each will have its own implementation of the convert method. If you define this class as an interface and leave the method without implementation, the same error occurs with the constructor without a bean